# Git installation error on ubuntu on Docker

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I want to install git. But this error is issued.

Before that, java and maven were installed normally.

What could be the problem?

```
root@2367f80df87a:/# apt install git
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  git-man less libasn1-8-heimdal libcurl3-gnutls liberror-perl libgdbm-compat4 libgdbm5 libgssapi3-heimdal libhcrypto4-heimdal libheimbase1-heimdal
  libheimntlm0-heimdal libhx509-5-heimdal libkrb5-26-heimdal libldap-2.4-2 libldap-common libnghttp2-14 libperl5.26 libpsl5 libroken18-heimdal librtmp1
  libsasl2-2 libsasl2-modules libsasl2-modules-db libssl1.0.0 libwind0-heimdal netbase openssh-client patch perl perl-modules-5.26 publicsuffix xauth
Suggested packages:
  gettext-base git-daemon-run | git-daemon-sysvinit git-doc git-el git-email git-gui gitk gitweb git-cvs git-mediawiki git-svn gdbm-l10n
  libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit | libsasl2-modules-gssapi-heimdal libsasl2-modules-ldap libsasl2-modules-otp libsasl2-modules-sql keychain libpam-ssh
  monkeysphere ssh-askpass ed diffutils-doc perl-doc libterm-readline-gnu-perl | libterm-readline-perl-perl make
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  git git-man less libasn1-8-heimdal libcurl3-gnutls liberror-perl libgdbm-compat4 libgdbm5 libgssapi3-heimdal libhcrypto4-heimdal libheimbase1-heimdal
  libheimntlm0-heimdal libhx509-5-heimdal libkrb5-26-heimdal libldap-2.4-2 libldap-common libnghttp2-14 libperl5.26 libpsl5 libroken18-heimdal librtmp1
  libsasl2-2 libsasl2-modules libsasl2-modules-db libssl1.0.0 libwind0-heimdal netbase openssh-client patch perl perl-modules-5.26 publicsuffix xauth
0 upgraded, 33 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
Need to get 14.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 89.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 perl-modules-5.26 all 5.26.1-6ubuntu0.3
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libgdbm5 amd64 1.14.1-6
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 perl-modules-5.26 all 5.26.1-6ubuntu0.3
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libgdbm-compat4 amd64 1.14.1-6
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Ign:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libperl5.26 amd64 5.26.1-6ubuntu0.3
0% [Connecting to security.ubuntu.com] [Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com]
```

And it goes on endlessly...

upd.

**Answer for @LinPy:**

```
root@2367f80df87a:/# apt-get update
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
0% [Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com]^C^[get update && apt-get install git
root@2367f80df87a:/# apt-get update && apt-get install git
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
```

When executing the "apt-get update" command, I have a similar error.

Comment: apt-get update && apt-get install git

Comment: @LinPy when executing the "apt-get update" command, I have a similar error. Updated the question above.

Comment: then check your internet connectivity from inside the container

Comment: @LinPy how can i check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a DNS issue in your docker engine.

You can test the theory by running:

```
docker run busybox ping archive.ubuntu.com
```

and see if it resolves.

Then, do the same, but with allowing host network or explicitly providing DNS:

```
docker run --network host busybox ping archive.ubuntu.com
docker run --dns 8.8.8.8 busybox ping archive.ubuntu.com
```

For a permanent solution, you might need to edit your `/etc/docker/daemon.json` and restart the docker engine:

```
{
    "dns": ["192.10.0.2", "8.8.8.8"]
}
```

[Reference here](https://medium.com/@faithfulanere/solved-docker-build-could-not-resolve-archive-ubuntu-com-apt-get-fails-to-install-anything-9ea4dfdcdcf2)